# what the meaning for the image about the package in java eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

what the meaning for the image about the package in java eclipse?

Comment: if memory serves correctly it means this package is empty (i.e. it has no classes that live on org.test.toolkit, only in the lower org.test.toolkit.example package).

Answer (score 1):

This means your folder is scheduled to be deleted on the next commit.

It is used when your project is under SCM using Subversion.

Go to

> *Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> Label Decorations*

to see the meaning of all used SVN icons, as shown below:

[image: svn icons]